# Useful MySQL Blogs/News sites?

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find any useful sites about MySQL news/tips other than mysqlperformanceblog.com.  Much of that sites postings are way over my head.

I was wondering if someone could share what other useful MySQL sites are out there?

Comment: I heard of this site called http://www.stackoverflow.com, it's ok

Comment: As Microsoft other not adopt animals as MVP for advertising. like lot's of person as mvp only posts ads of microsoft on their blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Planet MySQL:

http://planet.mysql.com/

It's an aggregation of many MySQL blogs. There's lots of good content on Planet MySQL, and you can use it to find other blogs which are at your level.

Enjoy!